# Magento: How to change base skin url based on browser (nginx)

Tags: magento, redirect, nginx, base-url

I'm running an https magento site on a nginx server. I'd like to serve my static content from a cdn (Amazon Cloudfront).

I can do this easily by changing the media/css/js urls from

www.mysite.com/xxx to cdn.mysite.com/xxx

however older browsers & operating systems (XP for example) don't support the SNI that makes this possible.

So, my question is:

How can I set my media/css/js base urls to be (www.mysite.com/xxx) when I detect that a user is running XP (for example), but leave them as cdn.mysite.com/xxx by default

I'd prefer not to have to set up multiple stores, just to be able to change these variables without the user knowing anything about it.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean by `however older browsers & operating systems (XP for example) don't support the SNI that makes this possible`. To me, your proposed solution is an unnecessary over complication and simply changing the urls is the correct approach. Just need to understand how you came to the conclusion that XP etc will not / can not access such urls.

Comment: It is true that IE6 does not support SNI and IE6 is only found on Windows XP but Chrome on XP does support it.  Global usage of IE6 is less than 0.3% (same as IE7) and the aim is to wipe it out completely.  I don't think anyone should be supporting that browser at all.

Comment: I'd love not to support it but, from looking at my analytics, I've had a few thousand dollars of business this year from customers using IE on XP & I can't afford to lose that level of business on a design principle.  According to Wikipedia, this problem affects all versions of IE on XP. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#support)

Answer (score 1):

I think it has nothing to see with nginx and can be done easily in the backend of Magento. You can go to system > configuration > design and click the button `add exception`.

Then you can write a regular expression in the `matched expression` field and a value to define the design that will be used in that case. The matched expression needs to match the user agents of the browsers that need to have a specific design. I think the user agent is more important than the operating system on the design aspects.

Comment: Thanks Christophe...  from what I've read, the OS is also a factor for this particular issue.  But adding a new theme with an exception might be the way to go for this.  Since it was just 3 variables that needed changed, I was hoping there might be a simpler way to do it.